# How to change device targets for XCode project programmatically?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, fastlane

I'm a React Native developer and I'm trying to nail down a workflow for publishing apps to the App Store/Google Play without having to touch XCode. Using fastlane I have almost everything automated except modifying the device deployment targets. When you init a React Native project, by default the app is for "iPhone Only" but most of my apps should be Universal (iPhone/iPad).

Using Node I can read/modify/write files easily, including plists. But I couldn't find a setting in the Info.plist that controlled this parameter. What file contains this setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that that setting is in the project file

```
YourProject.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
```

You can use the Gem `xcodeproj` to manipulate the project file programmatically within `fastlane`.

```
project = Xcodeproj::Project.open('path/to/YourProject.xcodeproj')
```